# Where can/should I learn C# or Unity

Tags: c#

I’ve recently got interested in getting into game development due to having too much time (I’m in high school). I’ve been thinking of getting into Unity specifically but I’m not sure where to start. Should I just mess around with Unity and Visual studio while slowly learning or should I learn C# first?

Comment: How to learn most efficiently is a very individual process. Everyone learns differently. The best approach for you depends on your personal learning style and your personal goals. Which is why we generally don't handle "what to learn when and how" questions on this website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think this question fits the community but I'm going to answer my two cents anyways.

If you have no previous programming experience you should learn to code first. Learn the basics of OOP( object oriented programing) and the syntax specifics of C#. As of where you can do that: There is no best place to learn, it highly depends on how you learn stuff etc. There are tons of recourse on the net. You say you are in high school. As far as I know most schools have programming classes. Maybe ask a teacher or try to join a club?

Game development might seem easy at first but it can get very complex very quickly. After getting the basics of programing first I suggest that you start with very simple games and build up from there. Generally starting building your dream game as your first game will end in disaster. My proffered progression that I always recommend is Pong -> Tetris -> Pacman.